# Pass large Strings in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using 3 frames in a jsp, one frame contains links for transactions. If one clicks on the link, I need to display 2 xmls (as Strings) in respective frames.

```
<display:table name="sessionScope.transactions" id="tTable">
  <display:column title="Transaction Id">
  <a href="javascript:somejavascript('<bean:write name='tTable'        
  property='requestXML' />','<bean:write name='tTable' property='responseXML' />');">

  <bean:write name='tranTable' property='transactionId' />

 </a>
</display:column>*
```

I want to bring evrything altogether while bringing links and when one clicks on the link I want to  pass those xmls as String in javascript function and dispaly it in frames.

```
somejavascript(req, resp){
  parent.frame2.location.href = req;
  parent.frame3.location.href = resp;
}
```

But I came to know that I cannot pass large data in javascript function , it breaks some javascript rule. Is there any workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should balance your quotes and escape inner quotes.

http://jsfiddle.net/9qdkc/

Overall, your approach is inappropriate. Avoid using `javascript:` links.

---

**How to improve?**

Present the data you want to pass into a JavaScript function as a separate node and assign a unique ID to this node.

Then add an attribute with this ID to the link node.

Now, iterate over all such links in your *separate* JavaScript file and [add click event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.addEventListener) to them.

In the handler of these listeners analyze the ID attribute of the clicked link and traverse the document using [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM)/[E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/e4x) to find the node with the corresponding ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can add eventlistener on link click as follows function load() { var el = document.getElementById("frame1"); el.addEventListener("click", function(){modifyText("requestXML")}, false); } But don't know how will I get requestXML in above code to pass it to modifyText function, as I can get it in jsp by looping through object in session scope. please let me know if there is a way to pass these request and response xmls in javascript function. Thanks

Comment: Something like this, with IDs -- http://jsfiddle.net/9qdkc/2/.
In place of HTML comments you should probably be using `CDATA` sections.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think your code will take me exactly where I want to go :) but Can you please give me an example of how to use CDATA in place of <bean:write name='tranTable' property='requestXML'/> as I can get requestXML from tranTable object only.

Comment: Actually, if your request and response nodes have valid syntax, you don't have to use CDATA. http://jsfiddle.net/9qdkc/3/. I suggest the rest you work out yourself.